# Swift 3 Calendar

Tags: swift, calendar

I just decided to covert my swift 2.0 code to 3.0 but I have a problem with Calendar. In swift 2.0 I did this to calculate difference between two date but It's not working anymore on Swift 3.0. What can I do? thanks

```
let from = dateArray[indexPath.row]
        let now = NSDate()
        let components : NSCalendarUnit = [.Second, .Minute, .Hour, .Day, .WeekOfMonth]
        let difference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(components, fromDate: from!, toDate: now, options: [])
```

Comment: How is it not working any more, what errors are you getting?

Comment: "Arguments label '_fromDate:, toDate:, options:)' do no match any available overloads'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is a lot of syntax changes and then there is a function called
`.compare` that you should use instead:

```
let from = dateArray[indexPath.row]
let now = NSDate()
let components : NSCalendar.Unit = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth]
let difference = NSCalendar.current.compare(from, to: now as Date, toGranularity: .day)
```

Change the `toGranularity` to the value you want.

Comment: The problem is that when I place components inside "toGranularity" it's throw an error saying "cannot covert a value of type "NSCalendar.Unit" to expected argument type "Calendar.Components""

Comment: You can only chose one calendar component in `toGranularity`. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatecomponents) is a list of the available components.